# Whitney sum formula for Pontryagin classes II

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I have read in several places that the total Pontryagin classes of real vector bundles satisfy a Whitney sum formula $p(E\oplus F) = p(E)\cdot p(F)$ modulo 2-torsion. I would like to understand the 2-torsion part better.

> Is there a reference which describes the difference between $p(E\oplus F)$ and $p(E)\cdot p(F)$, perhaps in terms of Bocksteins of Stiefel-Whitney classes of $E$ and $F$?

This question was previously part of [Whitney sum formula for Pontryagin classes I](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222576/whitney-sum-formula-for-pontryagin-classes); Qiaochu Yuan's answer to that question might be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brown, Edgar H., Jr.
The cohomology of BSOn and BOn with integer coefficients. 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 85 (1982), no. 2, 283–288.

Theorem 1.6, last sentence:

Under Whitney sum,
$p_q\mapsto  \sum_j r_{2q-j}\otimes r_j$, where
$r_{2s} = p_s$ and $r_{2s+1} = (\delta w_{2s})^2+ p_s\delta w_1$.

Comment: I don't suppose anyone wants to provide that sentence here to have the question and answer in one place?

Comment: @GregFriedman: I do.